# How to convert PDF to image with same resolution as original PDF

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am using Aspose.Pdf to convert PDF to Image and latter convert Image back to Pdf. I would like to keep resolution, width and height of the new Pdf same as original Pdf.

```
        using (var newDocument = new Document())
            {
                using (var originalDocument = new Document("c:\\source.pdf"))
                {
                    foreach (Aspose.Pdf.Page page in originalDocument.Pages)
                    {
                        if (page.Rotate != Aspose.Pdf.Rotation.None)
                        {
                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {

                                // Create Jpegdevice with specified attributes
                                // Width, Height, Resolution, Quality
                                // Quality [0-100], 100 is Maximum
                                // Create Resolution object
                                Resolution resolution = new Resolution(Convert.ToInt32(page.ArtBox.Width), Convert.ToInt32(page.ArtBox.Height));
                                JpegDevice device = new JpegDevice(resolution, 100);

                                // Convert a particular page and save the image to stream
                                device.Process(page, ms);                                    

                                var newPage = newDocument.Pages.Add();
                                // Set margins so image will fit, etc.
                                newPage.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = 0;
                                newPage.PageInfo.Margin.Top = 0;
                                newPage.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 0;
                                newPage.PageInfo.Margin.Right = 0;


                                // Create an image object
                                Aspose.Pdf.Image image1 = new Aspose.Pdf.Image();

                                // Set the image file stream
                                image1.ImageStream = ms;

                                // Add the image into paragraphs collection of the section
                                newPage.Paragraphs.Add(image1);

                                // YES, save after every page otherwise we get out of memory exception
                                newDocument.Save(txtFolder.Text + "\\out.pdf");
                            }                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newDocument.Pages.Add(page);
                            newDocument.Save(txtFolder.Text + "\\out.pdf");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Qustions**

1> The original PDF size is 18MB but the above code creates large file of size 163MB. I would like keep the size as it is or  least somewhat near to original file size by keeping the same resolution.

2>`Resolution` class also takes `int valueX` and `int valueY` parameters. And `JpegDevice` class takes `int width` and `int height` parameters. However it does not specify `unit`, weathers its in points, pixels, inches etc?

As per Aspose.Pdf documentation

> The conversion from point to pixel depends on an image's DPI (dots per
>   inch) property. For example, if an image's DPI is 96 (96 pixels for
>   each inch), and it is 100 points high, its height in pixels is (100 /
>   72) * 96 = 133.3. The general formula is: pixels = ( points / 72 ) *
>   DPI.

However that does not answer the question what unit the API is asking?

**Original Issue**
We get PDF from our clients. Some of the PDF we receive has rotation of 90 or 270 degree. However when you open them in Adobe or any other PDF viewer, the page's orientation is correct (it is not landscape or horizontal). All this mess i have to do becuase Aspose.Pdf cannot keep the same orientation when change the rotation to None. So suggested approach is convert PDF to Image and latter convert Image back to Pdf

https://forum.aspose.com/t/cannot-set-cropbox-on-rotated-page/201659/3
https://forum.aspose.com/t/remove-rotation-from-a-document-and-set-it-upright/29170

Comment: is aspose requirement for you?

Comment: regarding the size I assume you know that text and font are vector type that mean you can zoom in the pdf and would still have high quality. when you change to file, to keep that quality some how it will take more space that said reducing file size will reduce the quality, Is that ok with you?

Comment: we have been using aspose in the application i don't want to introduce new library, if possible.

Comment: Would you please share sample file so that I may investigate further. Moreover, default unit in Aspose.PDF API is point where 72 points equal 1 inch. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: you can take any PDF. I dont think the issue is with particular PDF file

Comment: Would you please try to set `IsBlackWhite` property of `Image` class, to true and then share your kind feedback if this suites your requirements and lessens the file size.